# Overwrite succesredirect for WFFM on MVC project

Tags: c#, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I'm trying to overwrite the `SuccesRedirect` class from the WFFM module.
I've found multiple blogs/websites saying how to do this ( like https://adesev.wordpress.com/2014/08/07/wffm-success-redirect/ )

But this doesn't work for me. I'm creating an MVC website, maybe this is the issue ? 
As there is a `Sitecore.forms.config` file and a `Sitecore.forms.MVC.config` file.
But I can't seem to find any documentation about this.

Does anyone know how to achieve this or where i can find some more information about this ?

Edit:

I'm using **WFFM Version 8.0 rev. 141217**.

What i've done is i've followed the blog i've listed above:

Changed Sitecore.forms.config file:
Changed the succesAction node with this:

```xml
  <successAction>
    <processor type="be.absi.kbs.extensions.SuccesRedirectWFFM, be.absi.kbs.extensions" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Form.Core.Pipelines.FormSubmit.FormatSuccessMessage, Sitecore.Forms.Core" />
  </successAction>
```

And i've created a class as follows: ( the assembly name is " be.absi.kbs.extensions " )

```cs
namespace be.absi.kbs.extensions
{
    class SuccesRedirectWFFM : ClientPipelineArgs
    {
        public void Process(SubmitSuccessArgs args)
        {
```

And what I'm trying to do is:

If the url has a returnUrl parameter, it needs to redirect to this url.
for example `myWebsite/Login?returnUrl=/Blogs`
Needs to redirect to user to the blog section after a successful login.

But so far i can't reach the Process method.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to change in the default SuccessRedirect behavior, what you've done to achieve this and what is not working for you?

Comment: Also which Sitecore and WFFM version you use?

Comment: See edit above  @MarekMusielak

Answer (score 2):

I think you're right and the reason why your code doesn't work is because you're using MVC.

First of all, do not replace the original `SuccessRedirect` with your `SuccesRedirectWFFM` action - add you action before the original one:

```
<successAction>
  <processor type="be.absi.kbs.extensions.SuccesRedirectWFFM, be.absi.kbs.extensions" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Form.Core.Pipelines.FormSubmit.SuccessRedirect, Sitecore.Forms.Core" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Form.Core.Pipelines.FormSubmit.FormatSuccessMessage, Sitecore.Forms.Core" />
</successAction>
```

Then in your code, check the value of `returnUrl` parameter in both current request url and in url referrer:

```cs
public class SuccesRedirectWFFM : ClientPipelineArgs
{
    public void Process(SubmitSuccessArgs args)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(args, "args");

        string returnUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request["returnUrl"]

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) 
        {
            returnUrl = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Query)["returnUrl"];
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        {
            args.AbortPipeline();
            WebUtil.Redirect(returnUrl, false);
        }
    }
}
```

The reason for that is in MVC when you submit the form, the request to the server is most probably an ajax call and it does not contain the original url.

Please remember that this is not a final version of the code - it should just point you in the right direction, e.g. you should add additional checks for the type of the Success action.

---

**EDIT:** You're right. I've check the code and it looks like in Sitecore MVC all the actions are executed within `FormController` class. I don't like the solution but it worked for me:

1. Change the `Controller` field of the `/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Mvc Form` item:

   [image]
2. Implement your own controller - if there is no `returnurl` defined, use default implementation:

```cs
namespace My.Assembly.Namespace
{
    public class FormController: SitecoreController, IHasModelFactory, IHasFormDataManager
    {
        public IModelFactory ModelFactory
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public IFormDataManager FormManager
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public FormController() : this((IModelFactory)Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject("wffm/modelFactory", true), (IFormDataManager)Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject("wffm/formDataManager", true))
        {
        }

        public FormController(IModelFactory modelFactory, IFormDataManager formDataManager)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(modelFactory, "modelFactory");
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(formDataManager, "formDataManager");
            this.ModelFactory = modelFactory;
            this.FormManager = formDataManager;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public override ActionResult Index()
        {
            return InnerController.Index();
        }

        [SubmittedFormHandler, ValidateHttpAntiForgeryToken, HttpPost]
        public virtual ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(FormModelBinder))] FormModel form)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(form, "form");
            if (this.FormManager == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            string returnUrl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["returnUrl"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            {
                returnUrl = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Query)["returnUrl"];
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            {
                return base.RedirectToRoute(MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName, new
                {
                    pathInfo = returnUrl.TrimStart(new char[]
                    {
                        '/'
                    })
                });
            }

            return InnerController.Index(form);
        }

        private Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Controllers.FormController InnerController
        {
            get
            {
                Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Controllers.FormController formController =
                    (Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Controllers.FormController)System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory().CreateController(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext, "Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Controllers.FormController, Sitecore.Forms.Mvc");
                formController.ControllerContext = this.ControllerContext;
                return formController;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've replace the succesAction node with the one you gave me, but the result is the same. The code/class is never reached.

Comment: You're right. See updated answer (the part after **EDIT:**).